# Using row.setValue() function with arcgisscripting?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3, error-999999

I'm trying to set column value `NULL`. I tried different ways to do that, I used `CalculateField_management` and `UpdateCursor` but i did not get success. when i used `CalculateField_management`. It says success no error but no data updated. Then i used `UpdateCursor` and it always gave me below error. Please help me in this.

```
'2016-01-06 11:20:37.563000
 Updating field values of  C:/Bhaskar/CO_LOAD/CO JAN/SIR 13996/SIR 9999/TEST_STAGE_ELEC_22.sde 
Cursor created.Row extracted.Curent field values is  TESTING. Updating field values of  ABC_TEST
Unable to add field:  (<type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>, RuntimeError('ERROR
99999: Error executing function.',), <traceback object at 0x3DB01148>)>>> '
```

I am using bellow code in PYTHON 2.5.1 and ArcGIS 9.3.1.

```
import xlrd
import os.path
import DomainAssignmnetScriptForSde
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
import ctypes
import re
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting
from datetime import datetime


Tkinter.Tk().withdraw() # Close the root window
#open the Dailog box to browse the database
databasePath =tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title='Select Sde File')

file=open("ValidationReport.txt","a")
currentDateTime = datetime.now()
print str(currentDateTime)
file.write(str(currentDateTime) + '\n')
file.write("..............Validation Strated..........\n") 


# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp  = arcgisscripting.create()

# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Data Management Tools.tbx")

def UpdateField():
try:       

    fclass= databasePath + "/SEU_GIS_ELEC.Cameras"
    gp.workspace=fclass
    #gp.workspace=databasePath
    #gp.CalculateField_management("SEU_GIS_ELEC.SecUGConductor", "OPERATINGVOLTAGE", None, "PYTHON")

    rows = gp.UpdateCursor(fclass)
    print "Cursor created."
    row = rows.Next()
    print "Row extracted."
    while row:
        print "Curent field values is  " + str(row.getValue("LOCATIONLINK"))
        #row.OPERATINGVOLTAGE = None
        #myVal='ABC_TEST'
        #row.setValue("LOCATIONLINK", myVal)
        row.setValue("LOCATIONLINK", None)
        #print row.OPERATINGVOLTAGE
        print "Updating field values of  " + str(row.getValue("LOCATIONLINK"))
        rows.updateRow(row)
        print "Updating field values of  " + str(row.getValue("LOCATIONLINK"))

        row = rows.Next()
    del row
    del rows
    file.write("........Processing finished.........."  +'\n')          
except:
    print "Unable to add field: ", sys.exc_info()

UpdateField()
file.write("..............Validation finished..........\n")           

file.close()
```

Comment: Are you certain that you can edit the feature class that you are targeting? My 9.3 is very rusty, but I remember it being quite a bit more complicated to edit SDE classes in 9.3.

Comment: Yes, I am able to edit both feature class. In fact also think same way and i tried same thing on different connections and different feature classes and i got same result.

Comment: Have you tried it with a file geodatabase as the target? Oh, and what version is your SDE and what database is it running on? I think you can get the 99999 error from a client/version mismatch for your database client software

Comment: I did not tried with file geodatabase but i can give a shot. I am running it on ORACLE 11.0 and my SDE file is currently pointing to a version. But i also tried with a NON-version SDE connection.

Comment: I am not able to decide why "CalculateField_management" not giving me any error or warning. It just execute and i get nothing in output.

Comment: I just re-run the code on File geodatabase and it ran successfully. Now i am not sure  why it was causing problem in SDE environment.